# Combine inner arrays into one

Tags: php

I have this array of userids. I want to combine the child userid arrays into one array within the parent arrays.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1610
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1614
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1616
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1610
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1614
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1616
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [userid] => 1618
            )

    )
```

My desired result would look like...

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [userids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1610
                [1] => 1614
                [2] => 1616
            )
)

[1] => Array
    (
        [userids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1610
                [1] => 1614
                [2] => 1616
                [3] => 1618
            )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array and use array_column to flatten the subarrays.

```
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $res[][key($sub[0]) . "s"] = array_column($sub, 'userid');
}

var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/A68VA

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!